# How to reject characters/ letters in a java program

Tags: java, printf, invalid-characters

When the program asks the user to input 10 elements (numbers), but the user entered any letter or word, I want the program to display "INVALID INPUT". I tried an if statement but it doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

This is my code:

```
        int [] Array = new int[10];
        int index;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter 10 elements:");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Array[i] = input.nextInt();
            }

        System.out.print("Enter an index you want to retrieve: ");
        index = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Element at index "+index+" is " + Array[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `try-catch` and catch a `InputMismatchException`, where you can then handle it accordingly.

Like so:

```
    try{
       int [] Array = new int[10];
        int index;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 10 elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter an index you want to retrieve: ");
        index = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Element at index "+index+" is " + Array[index]);
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("INVALID INPUT");
    }
```

For example, when I input:

```
spectric is not cool
```

I get:

```
INVALID INPUT
```

*Because spectric is cool*

Comment: Apparently someone doesn't like our answers.

Comment: @WJS They are perfectly fine answers to me. Wonder why.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:  You need to catch the input mismatch and then continue taking input. It is important to  update the loop counter to allow for all 10 inputs to be taken.

```
int [] Array = new int[10];
int index;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter 10 elements:");

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
           Array[i] = input.nextInt();
        } catch(InputMismatchException ie) {
            System.out.println("Bad input - please re-enter");
            i--; // update loop;
            input.nextLine();// clear bad input from buffer scanner.
        }
     }

   System.out.print("Enter an index you want to retrieve: ");
   index = input.nextInt();

   System.out.print("Element at index "+index+" is " + Array[index]);
```